# rendered attribute not working with request parameter

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using JSF2.2 with primefaces 5.0. I have a xhtml file where there are two file Uploads where one should always be visible while other should be visible only when request parameter, named signmethod, is JAVAME.

```
            <h:panelGrid>
                <h:panelGroup>
                    <h:outputLabel for="selected_signmethod" value="Selected Signethod : "/>
                    <h:outputText id="selected_signmethod" value="#{param.signmethod}" />
                </h:panelGroup>                    
                <h:panelGroup>
                    <b>Select file(s) to upload:</b>
                </h:panelGroup>                    
            </h:panelGrid>                
            <h:form id="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <p:message for="file_upload"/>
                <p:fileUpload id="file_upload" allowTypes="#{fileUploadView.allowedTypes}" label="Select file" fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadView.handleFileUpload}"
                              mode="advanced" dragDropSupport="false" update="growl" multiple="true" fileLimit="5"/>
                <p:message for="javame_upload"/>

                <h:panelGroup rendered="#{param.signmethod == 'JAVAME'}" >
                    <b>Select corresponding jar file(s) to upload:</b>
                <p:fileUpload id="javame_upload" allowTypes="" label="Select Jar file for javame" fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadView.handleFileUpload}"
                              mode="advanced" dragDropSupport="false" multiple="true" fileLimit="5"/>
                </h:panelGroup>

                <p:commandButton ajax="false" id="signProceed" value="Proceed" action="#{fileUploadView.submit}"/>
            </h:form>
```

But this seems to be not happening. Second upload component is not getting rendered at all. I am also printing value of param.signmethod so that to be sure that right value is getting into  param.signmethod, which is correct. So whats stopping this component to get rendered.

Managed Bean code :

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class FileUploadView implements Serializable {

@ManagedProperty(value = "#{signBundleBean}")
private SignBundleBean signBundleBean;
static String uploadDirRoot = InitialisationHelper.getUploadDirRoot();
transient Map<String, Object> sessionMap;
ArrayList<Signing> signings;
String username;
SignMethod signMethod;


public FileUploadView() {
    System.out.println("NEW FileUploadView created.");
}

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    System.out.println("@POstConstruct FileuploadView");
    System.out.println("signMethod : " + signMethod);
    sessionMap = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap();        
    signings = signBundleBean.getSignings();
    username = (String) sessionMap.get("username");        
}

public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent e) {
    String signId = "" + DatabaseHelper.genrateSigningId();
    FacesContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    UploadedFile uploadedFile = e.getFile();
    String filename = uploadedFile.getFileName();
    if (signId.equals("-1")) {
        FacesMessage fm = new FacesMessage();
        fm.setDetail("Database Connection not working. Please try later.");
        fm.setSummary("DBConnection_Error");
        fm.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
        //ctx.addMessage(null, fm);
        ctx.addMessage("uploadForm:file_upload", fm);
        return;
    }
    if (username == null) {
        FacesMessage fm = new FacesMessage();
        fm.setDetail("You are not in session to upload.");
        fm.setSummary("Session_Error");
        fm.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
        ctx.addMessage("uploadForm:file_upload", fm);
        return;
    }

    Signing sg;
    sg = new Signing(signId, username, filename, signMethod, false);
    signings.add(sg);
    System.out.println("Signing added : " + sg);
    signBundleBean.setMaxParameters(SignParametersInitialisation.getNumberOfParameters(signMethod));

    try {
        InputStream is = uploadedFile.getInputstream();
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(sg.getUploadfile());
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        int read = 0;
        while ((read = is.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            os.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }
        os.flush();
        sg.setUploaded(true);
        is.close();
        os.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        signings.remove(sg);
        Logger.getLogger(FileUploadView.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    FacesMessage fm = new FacesMessage();
    fm.setDetail(filename);
    fm.setSummary("FileUploaded");
    fm.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO);
    //ctx.addMessage(null, fm);
    ctx.addMessage(null, fm);
    System.out.println(sg + " File uploaded to " + sg.getUploadfile());

}


}
```

Comment: can you post your managed bean code?

Comment: Either you're not running the code you think you're running, or the parameter value is not exactly `JAVAME`. Whitespace perhaps?

Comment: I am accessing the page like : /FileUpload.xhtml?i=1&server=ADC&signmethod=JAVAME so the signmethod cannot have whitespace and param.signmethod is printing the correct value.

Comment: Managed Bean Code added to the code

Comment: give it a try after you replace the rendered clause with this (case correction): `"#{param.signMethod == 'JAVAME'}"`

Comment: its not working with param.signMethod as paramter name is signmethod and its value is printing correctly at the top of the page. Although its working with fileUPloadView.signMethod as I am setting this property at before rendering the view using f:viewParam.